# String comparison in java does not gives the desired results

Tags: java, string, comparison, equals

I tried with the following class :

```
public class EqualMethodTestWithNew {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String value = "xxx";
        String name = new String("xxx") ;

        System.out.println("hascode : value : "+value.hashCode());
        System.out.println("hascode : name  : "+name.hashCode());

        if (value == name) {
            System.out.println("equal == 1");
        } else {
            System.out.println("false == 1");
        }

    }
}
```

though the hasCode is same for the both variable it prints the `false == 1`. could some one explain the reason why?

thanks

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun We should have a popup `Is this a question about string equality?` while posting new question!!!

Comment: @NarendraPathai I think we should have an "auto-punch" feature that come from the screen when someone ask about `==` vs `equals`.

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun That would be so convenient :D and fun tooo. I would ask this question and get a punch every day then ;)

Comment: @NarendraPathai Be careful.. at some stage it'll be a gun..

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun Ahhh.. This is cool. Can we take it to meta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand what exactly is happening when you execute the 2 string statements.

```
    String value = "xxx";
```

The above line creates a new compile time constant string which does into the [String intern pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_intern_pool).

```
    String name = new String("xxx") ;
```

But in this case, since you're using the `new` operator, it creates a new String object which goes in the object heap. It does not have the same address as the one which was created in the previous statement.

The [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29) method is based on the contents of the String which are the same, but that doesn't mean that they both refer to the same String object in the memory.

```
s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1] // would return same value for all String objects having the same content
```

To compare the values, you need to use `equals()` method.

And if you want to compare the object references use the `==` operator. In your case, since both refer to difference objects, you get the output as `false`.

Alternatively, you can ask the compiler to check and fetch the reference of a String with the same value already existing in the String pool by using the [`intern()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) method.

```
String value = "xxx";
String name = new String("xxx");
name = name.intern(); // getting reference from string pool
```

Now you'll get the output as `equal == 1` when your do `if (value == name) {`.

Answer (score 1):

String should be compared with [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method, not `==`. You are trying the check the equality of the memory address of both instances (actually they are not) instead of the value in the String instances. So, use

```
if(value.equals(name)) {
    System.out.println("equal == 1");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `equals` method instead of `==` opertaor.

```
if (value.equals(name)) {
   System.out.println("equal == 1");
} else {
   System.out.println("false == 1");
}
```

Note that:

```
== tests for reference equality.

.equals() tests for value equality.
```

Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your code is not working is that `==` tests whether the reference to the object is the same, and that is not your case. To compare the value of the string, you need to use the `.equals(String str)` method.

```
if (value.equals(name)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are compared using equal() method. == compares the two objects are equal are not.